# Silverlight OOB to tray through COM

Tags: c#, silverlight, com, silverlight-4.0

Until Silverlight 5, we don't have PInvoke and we can't minimize OOB apps to tray, but I wonder if it's possible to use COM api in full trust sl app to minimize the application in system tray? I'm not very fluent in COM/OLE, so anyone knows any com object which can minimize a window to tray?

If windows doesn't provide such COM object, is it possible to write one and make a setup.exe deployment package? What's your thought about?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Native Extensions for Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl).

Comment: They don't have what I want :(

Comment: Have you found a solution? Since Silverlight 5 extends features of the ‘Trusted Application’ model (Call existing unmanaged code directly from within Silverlight with PInvoke) it should now be possible to minimize OOB apps to tray, http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/future/#trusted